# How to display large image properly in fixed size div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a lot of large images with different size(300x400, 500x300...). And I want to display those large images properly scaled within a fixed size div.

For example, I have a 200x200 div, and a 500*300 image.

```
|--------------------|
|                    |
|                    |
|   div(200x200)     |
|                    |
|                    |
|--------------------|

|--------------------------------|
|                                |
|                                |
|   image(500x300)               |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
|--------------------------------|
```

So the width of the image will be 200 pixels and height will proportionally scale and become 300 * 200 / 500 = 125 pixels. The image will look smaller, but it keeps its proportions and will still look good.

```
|--------------------|
|      Blank         |
|--------------------|
|                    |
|   Image(200x125)   |     # div (200x200)
|                    |
|--------------------|
|      Blank         |
|--------------------|
```

How can I do that? Is there any javascript libs to do this?

Comment: try `img { max-width: 100%; vertical-align: middle; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `max-width` and `max-height` css properties to the `img` tag.

```
img {
     max-width: 100%;
     max-height: 100%;
}
```

This will keep your image in aspect ratio with respect to its parent container.

When we don't know the image width and height, I suggest to use the following css code, which automatically aligns the image in the parent container.

```
.image-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    height:150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.image-wrapper img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/y43uzbgk/)

Doing the same using `background` css property:

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/y43uzbgk/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```css
.divclass img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <img src="imagename.jpg" class="img">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img{
max-width:100%
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You also need max-height:100% in case the image is tall instead of wide.

Answer (score 0):

On your fixed div use:

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

And on your `img` use:

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```